# whats wrong in this code?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

whats wrong in this code

i have a Imagebutton2 in gridview whose commandname is xxx and i have added modalpopup extendar panel2 with ImageButton2 i want when image button 2 will be clicked then the modalpopup will display and retrieve the values from selected gridview row to the literal3 control of panel 1 which acts as a modalpopup control for gridview ?

```
 Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand
        Dim myrow As GridViewRow = CType(CType(e.CommandSource, Control).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
        Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
        If e.CommandName = "xxx" Then
            Dim lab5 As Label = DirectCast(myrow.FindControl("Label5"), Label)
            Dim lit3 As Literal = Me.Panel2.FindControl("Literal3")
            lit3.Text = lab5.Text
        End If
        End Sub
```

Comment: You might get a better clue if you remove `On Error Resume Next`...

Comment: I think your keyboard is missing the '.' and ',' keys.

Answer (score 1):

Many things can fail:

- e.CommandArgument may not be an integer
- e.CommandSource may not be of Control type
- the NamingContainer may not be of GridViewRow type
- myRow can be null, at least when the code is ran
- the "Label5" control may not be found, or may not be of Label type, when the code is ran
- the "Literal3" control may not be found (null ref) or may not be of Literal type, when the code is ran
  ...